# c# WPF selected item from listbox bound to datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I'm building a wpf application and I made my database using Entity Framework code first.

I have a list box bound to a table

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstDishes" Height="415" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,1032,42" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="281" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="#FFDDC9B0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="15" MouseDoubleClick="lstDishes_MouseDoubleClick">
```

**XAML.CS**

```
var dish = (from Dish in db.Dishes
            select Dish).ToList();
lstDishes.ItemsSource = dish;
lstDishes.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
```

On item double click, I would like to show selected item in another listbox.

I was trying to manage it, but before I was doing some kind of trial for the selected item, showing a message box on double click

```
private void lstDishes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You selected: " + lstDishes.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

But the result of my messagebox is this:

[image]

Of course it's not readable.

- How can I get the selected item as it's shown in listbox?
- Do you have any suggestion for the next step where I'm going to binde the selected item to another listbox?

**Edit**

Since my listbox is bound to a table in database, I had to cast the selected item as my type of entity.

Comment: What exactly were you hoping the `MessageBox` would show? This is the normal behavior of `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the type of the selected item and

```
private void lstDishes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var Selected =  lstDishes.SelectedItem as Dish;
   MessageBox.Show("You selected: " + Selected.Description));   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest any tutorial on this argument? I took a deep look in these days but I couldn't find anything so straightforward..

Comment: did it work? yes there are plenty of tutorials. i will send a book, if you share email

Comment: Yes, it did. My email is : koosshh56@gmail.com . Thanks for everything